# Load external XAML file using LoadComponent

Tags: wpf

I have found some [evidence](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=ru#tCmzmCmTMPc/samples/python/bubbles/app/app.xaml&q=Application.LoadComponent%20absolute%20path) that this is possible,

```
self.scene = Canvas()
Application.LoadComponent(self.scene, Uri('app.xaml', UriKind.Relative))
```

but my code is failing:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Canvas scene = new Canvas();
        Application.LoadComponent(scene, new Uri("app.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

I am using the same app.xaml with 'Build Action: None', and 'Copy always".

```
<Canvas
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="System.Windows.Controls.Canvas"
    x:Name="ball_design" >

    <Canvas x:Name="workaround_canvas" >

        <TextBlock x:Name="fps" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Height="40" Canvas.ZIndex="10000" Text="-- fps" />
    <Canvas x:Name="wpfe_ball_0" Width="52" Height="52" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="30">
      <!-- Layer 3/<Group>/<Path> -->
      <Path Opacity="0.900000" StrokeThickness="2.000000" Stroke="#ffa6d000" StrokeMiterLimit="1.000000" Fill="#ffcbff00" Data="F1 M 51.000000,26.000000 C 51.000000,39.806641 39.807129,51.000000 26.000000,51.000000 C 12.192871,51.000000 1.000000,39.806641 1.000000,26.000000 C 1.000000,12.193359 12.192871,1.000000 26.000000,1.000000 C 39.807129,1.000000 51.000000,12.193359 51.000000,26.000000 Z"/>

      <!-- Layer 3/<Group>/<Path> -->
      <Path Opacity="0.740000" Data="F1 M 43.143066,13.087891 C 50.602051,22.888672 49.009766,36.642578 39.590332,43.812500 C 30.170898,50.980469 16.489258,48.842773 9.032715,39.042969 C 1.573242,29.240234 3.166016,15.486328 12.584961,8.316406 C 22.003906,1.149414 35.685547,3.285156 43.143066,13.087891 Z">
        <Path.Fill>
          <RadialGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" GradientOrigin="156.791016,170.453125" Center="156.791016,170.453125" RadiusX="53.626404" RadiusY="53.626404">
            <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
              <GradientStop Offset="0.000000" Color="#ffffffff"/>
              <GradientStop Offset="0.361685" Color="#fff5f7dd"/>
              <GradientStop Offset="0.415730" Color="#ffebf0bc"/>
              <GradientStop Offset="1.000000" Color="#ffcbff00"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
              <MatrixTransform Matrix="1.190000,0.165000,-0.165000,-1.281300,-113.414185,241.757843" />
            </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
          </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Path.Fill>
      </Path>

      <!-- Layer 3/<Group>/<Path> -->
      <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 23.100586,9.477539 C 24.741699,11.634766 23.116211,15.630859 19.470703,18.404297 C 15.825684,21.178711 11.540039,21.678711 9.899414,19.522461 C 8.258301,17.365234 9.883789,13.369141 13.529297,10.594727 C 17.174316,7.821289 21.459961,7.321289 23.100586,9.477539 Z"/>
    </Canvas>
    <TextBlock x:Name="dbgwin" FontSize="10" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="250" Height="500" Width="200" Text="IronPython DLR" />

  </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

I get IOException: Cannot locate resource 'app.xaml'.

What is a solution?

Comment: Hm... Code I mentioned is the SilverLight code, so may be the LoadComponent can't be used to load external files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that external XAML file can't be loaded by LoadComponent.

I checked the source code:

```
    public static void LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator) 
    {
        ...

        // Passed a relative Uri here.
        // needs to resolve it to Pack://Application.
        //..\..\ in the relative Uri will get stripped when creating the new Uri and resolving to the 
        //PackAppBaseUri, i.e. only relative Uri within the appbase are created here
        Uri currentUri = new Uri(BaseUriHelper.PackAppBaseUri, resourceLocator); 

        ...
    }
```

So the resourceLocator SHOULD be a relative path. And it will be treated under application:/// authority.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#The_Pack_URI_Scheme)

> WPF supports two authorities:
>   application:/// and siteoforigin:///.
>   The application:/// authority
>   identifies application data files that
>   are known at compile time, including
>   resource and content files. The
>   siteoforigin:/// authority identifies
>   site of origin files.

Possible data files are:

- Packages and parts are analogous to
  applications and files, where an
  application (package) can include
  one or more files (parts),
  including:
- Resource files that are compiled
  into the local assembly.
- Resource files that are compiled
  into a referenced assembly.
- Resource files that are compiled
  into a referencing assembly.
- Content files.
- Site of origin files.

The first 4 files are accessible with application://, but I am looking for external files, so the only option is "Content file".

So I turned app.xaml into content file (details are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx#Content_Files))

1. Build Action to Content
2. Copy to Output Directory to Copy always
3. [assembly: AssemblyAssociatedContentFile("app.xaml")]

As result such exception was thrown: 'application/xaml+xml' ContentType is not valid.

```
    public static void LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator) 
    {
        ...

            if (!MimeTypeMapper.BamlMime.AreTypeAndSubTypeEqual(contentType)) 
            {
                throw new Exception(SR.Get(SRID.ContentTypeNotSupported, contentType)); 
            }
        ...
    }
```

So the LoadComponent expects 'application/baml+xml' instead of 'application/xaml+xml'.

I don't know a way to store xaml as external file in 'application/baml+xml', so assume the task has no solution.

Comment: The latest research shows that having BAML we can load it. Will change response latter.

Comment: how do you get the BAML?

Answer (score 5):

I got this to work.  My specific goal was to load a ResourceDictionary into the App class so I could have custom skins loaded from raw XAML files.  Here's how.  First, in App.xaml, Add the following:

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        LoadSkin("Skins/Skin1.xaml");

    }

    private void LoadSkin(string FilePath) {
        XmlReader XmlRead = XmlReader.Create(FilePath);
        Application.Current.Resources = 
            (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(XmlRead);
        XmlRead.Close();
    }
```

Create a "bin\Debug\Skins" folder and added a "Skin1.xaml" with the following content:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonAStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

---

**Specific to Skins**

In this particular case, you have to make sure you are using the style resources correctly in your individual windows.  Here's an example:

```
<Button 
    Name="button1" 
    Style="{DynamicResource ButtonAStyle}" 
    Click="button1_Click"
>Button</Button>
```

Here's a neat trick to try.  In button1_Click(), try adding the same code you did in App.OnStartUp() above but with "Skin2.xaml" with "Red" as the background color for your buttons.  The skin changes instantly without requiring a reload of the app or window.

Comment: 1. What is your VS version? I don't see such build action "Content Copy to Output" in VS2008? 2. Are you sure that Skin1.xaml is ONLY copied, and not compiled into .exe as a resource?

Comment: I'm using VS 2008. Looks like I fooled myself, though. This works for me if I set "Build Action" to "Content". If I just put loose files in bin\Debug\Skins\, it doesn't work. :-P  I'm looking for a fix now.

Comment: Fixed.  The key was using a XamlReader instead of Application.LoadComponent().  I've updated the code here to reflect it.

Comment: Unfortunately, XamlReader.Load will work only for xaml files with out events in it

Comment: This helped me with an addin where Application.LoadComponent was trying to find my ResourceDictionary in the host application.

Answer (score 0):

You will need Absolute File URI including entire file://c:/ etc.. because Relative is used inside the application's resources only.

Comment: Now I get ArgumentException: Cannot use absolute URI.

Answer (score 0):

In order for LoadComponent to work on an XAML resource, it will need to have a build action of "Page". Then the LoadComponent works, even in a Console app.

This could be useful when wanting to access sample data generated from Blend in a server app.